# how may I find the filesystem image of the OS with initramfs

Tags: boot, kali-linux, dual-boot, initramfs, tails-os

I want to install Tails on my Hard Drive alongside Kali Linux.

So I installed Kali on the system and prepared Grub2.

I also created a partition of 3GB for my Tails installation, formatted it to FAT32, named it Tails and `dd`ed the tails archive onto it. Now I went to my `grub.cfg` and put in the lines from the Tails `grub.cfg` file.

Additionally I created a partition with the name "TailsData" of additional 3GB.

Now, if I go to my bootloader, I may select Kali as well as Tails.

Booting into Kali works fine, but now if I try to boot into Tails it rejects me with initramfs telling me

`initramfs unable to find a medium containing the live file system`

Now for the sake of helping out I inserted in `grub.cfg` the UUID of the partition as a fix - as it may never ever change...

Still I do not get into the system, since I googled this issue I found lots and lots of initramfs errors like mine but none of them seems to fit my case unfortunately...

Additional Data:

This is my `live64.cfg` which is loaded to extend `syslinux.cfg`

```
include menu.cfg

label live
    menu label Tails 5.19.1
    kernel /live/vmlinuz
    append initrd=/live/initrd.img boot=live ignore_uuid config live-media=removable nopersistence noprompt timezone=Etc/UTC splash noautologin module=Tails slab_nomerge slub_debug=FZ mce=0 vsyscall=none init_on_free=1 mds=full,nosmt page_alloc.shuffle=1 randomize_kstack_offset=on  quiet
    sysappend 0x40000

label livefailsafe
    menu label Tails (Troubleshooting Mode)
    kernel /live/vmlinuz
    append initrd=/live/initrd.img boot=live ignore_uuid config live-media=removable nopersistence noprompt timezone=Etc/UTC splash noautologin module=Tails slab_nomerge slub_debug=FZ mce=0 vsyscall=none init_on_free=1 mds=full,nosmt page_alloc.shuffle=1 randomize_kstack_offset=on  noapic noapm nodma nomce nolapic nosmp
    sysappend 0x40000

#label floppy
#   localboot 0x00

#label disk1
#   localboot 0x80

#label disk2
#   localboot 0x81

#label nextboot
#   localboot -1
```

Here I added `ignore_uuid` - but it doesn't change my outcome...

Here is my `grub.cfg`

```
    set root='(hd1,4)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ***UUID-XYZ***
    echo "Loading the Linux kernel..."
    linux /live/vmlinuz initrd=/live/initrd.img boot=live config live-media=removable nopersistence noprompt timezone=Etc/UTC splash noautologin module=Tails slab_nomerge slub_debug=FZ mce=0 vsyscall=none init_on_free=1 mds=full,nosmt page_alloc.shuffle=1 randomize_kstack_offset=on FSUUID=***UUID-XYZ*** quiet
    echo "Loading the initramfs..."
    initrd /live/initrd.img
    echo "Booting..."
    boot
```

If more information is needed, please ask.

Note: For now I managed to run the ISO file through Grub... But the ISO may not access the "tailsData" partition for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tails is designed to be used from removable media, so it looks for removable media that would contain the tails archive file. A hard disk is not classified as removable media, so the Tails initramfs is looking at the wrong place.

You should remove the `live-media=removable` boot option to make Tails look for its archive in non-removable drives too.

Installing Tails on the hard drive defeats a big part of the purpose of Tails, i.e. the ability to hide that you're using Tails. The presence of Tails on the hard drive can be a big shiny sign that you are trying to hide something. If searched, it increases the probability of this scenario:

[image: the searcher might force you to show what is inside your Tails installation.]

A small USB stick is easier to keep hidden, or dispose of if necessary.